# How do I kill Pols Voices?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

The Pols Voices I am encountering in the Bottle Grotto seem to be pretty immune to damage. Sword strikes won't kill them, and I don't really have anything else that I can use, it being so early in the game.

[image: Pols Voice]

Sorry for the tiny picture, but that is the enemy I am talking about.

How can I kill it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pols Voice are susceptible to a number of non-sword attacks. **Bombs**, **arrows**, **bomb arrows**, and my personal favorite tactic of **throwing pots at them** are all functional for damage. If you're in Bottle Grotto, you're probably going to need to throw a pot.

In the instruction booklet for the original *Legend of Zelda*, it was mentioned that Pols Voice have a weakness to sound. While this never manifested in the original game for US audiences (as it required the microphone in the original Famicom's controllers), it manifests in Link's Awakening as **instant death when hearing the Ocarina** (specifically, play the 1st song).

Comment: The original Famicom controllers had a microphone? Neat!

Answer (score 3):

They are able to be destroyed by jars or bombs if there are jars in the room or if you have any bombs.

Answer (score 2):

Pick up a nearby pot with your all-new gloves and throw it onto him.

Warning, the following video demonstrates the killing, but also spoils how to solve the room you find the pols voice in.